# Event Invitations Not Working in Graph or Rest API

Tags: facebook, invite

I'm not able to send event invitations from either the Graph or REST API.  I initially was trying to do it through the Graph API, but after seeing the following question I decided to try the REST API.

[How to invite a users friends to an event? Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346634/how-to-invite-a-users-friends-to-an-event-facebook-graph-api)

When I attempt to use the Graph API from the PHP SDK as such..

```
$facebook->api('/' . $event_id . '/invited/?users=' . $friend_ids_string, 'POST');
```

where $friend_ids_string is a string of user ids "user_id1,user_id2,user_id3" I receive the following error: "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Permissions error"

When I use the REST API called through the Graph API:

```
$facebook->api(array(
  'method' => 'events.invite',
  'eid' => $event_id,
  'uids' => $friend_ids,
));
```

I receive basically the same error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 200: Permissions error".

I have verified that my application has all of the necessary permissions set (create_event, rsvp_event,user_events,friends_events), and I'm only trying to add invitees to an event that was created by my app.

Does anyone know what could be causing this or a good work around?

Comment: The REST API is deprecated, please upgrade to using Graph API.

Comment: I tried the Graph & REST APIs.

Comment: I confirmed that in the Graph API that adding invites to an app created event gets the 200 errors.  You should report it as a bug to http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and post back a link to it so other users who stumble across this question can see that it was logged.

Comment: I got into same problem. My app was working fine using graph api for months, recently started getting "200: Permissions error" :(
Anyone know any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer.

I noticed that whenever one of the users that you are trying to invite are already invited then the entire POST fails with a #200 error. So you need to check the users in your coma delimited string against the users already invited to the event.

However even if I do that it still fails sometimes.

So I am not sure what the complete answer is.

Maybe there's a limit to how many you can post at once. Maybe one of the users that you are trying to invite has blocked your user in the past - I wonder how we could check this.

Comment: Yup pretty sure that's the issue. Trying to invite a friend who blocked your invites. Now only if there were a way to programmatically  check that