# How to invite a users friends to an event in Facebook Graph API 2.8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to invite users friends to an event in Facebook's Graph API 2.8. I've already did a lot of researches and found some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346634/how-to-invite-a-users-friends-to-an-event-facebook-graph-api) but unfortunately the API explorer tells me `(#12) invited field is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher`.

```
POST /EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID
POST /EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3
```

Another try was to use the `me/invitabel_friends` edge but this is used for games only and going in the wrong direction, I think.

There are also no useful information in the Graph API's [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) regarding an alternative way to invite friends in 2.4 and higher.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: There is no way to invite people to an event using the API

Comment: Hell, this is annoying.  Like many Facebook group Admins, we have over 1,000 members, and it's unbelievable that, to invite all members to an event, we have to use an iPhone/iPad (NOT an Android) and individually tap on event member to invite them.  Ridiculous.  ;-(