# Is it possible to let user invite friends to an event with graph api?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, graph

I apologize if this is a duplicate but i couldn't find an answer to my question.

I know that it's not possible to invite user friends to an event using graph api but maybe it's possible to open a external window/modal and let user select invitable friends that are not yet associated with my web app??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346634/how-to-invite-a-users-friends-to-an-event-facebook-graph-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invite a users friends to an event? Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346634/how-to-invite-a-users-friends-to-an-event-facebook-graph-api)

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to invite users using graph api, i'm looking an alternative way to let user invite friends manually. By alternative i mean maybe opening a new window with facebook invite dialog or something.

Answer (score 0):

The possibility to invite users to an Event got removed with v2.5 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/archive#version2.5

There is no other way. Invitable Friends got removed recently, btw.