# facebook graph api : adding external URL as image to EVENT

Tags: php, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

I use below parameters to create an event via facebook graph api

```
$attachment =  array(   'access_token'  => $token,
                          'name' => $event_name,
                                'start_time' => $event_start,
                                'privacy_type' => $event_privacy
 );
```

how can i attach an external URL as an image to an event in it,

P.s : I am using curl so i need to use external image url

Comment: See this link it has answer which you want.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095099/attach-image-to-facebook-event-php-sdk-rest-or-graph-api