# Facebook Graph-API using curl - Create event with picture failed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I have tested the codes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070422/creating-a-facebook-event-and-publishing-a-cover-photo) and [this](http://rvieiraweb.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/create-event-on-facebook-using-graph-api-curl/) 
but it doesn't work.

The event is created successfully but the image is not published.

Here is my actual code:

```
require_once '../admini/config.php';

$t = getToken('appID', 'appSecret');

$file = 'Koala.jpg';
$arrData = array(
    'name' => 'Test Event',
    'start_time' => '2015-07-04', //ISO-8601 format - With Time  -     2012-07-04T19:00:00-0700
    //'end_time' => '', //optional
    'description' => 'Das erste Test-Event',
    'location' => 'Deggendorf', //Just a name
    'location_id' => '103091806397289', //place id - inserts a link to place fb page
    'ticket_url' => 'url', //URL to buy a ticket for the event
    'no_feed_story' => FALSE, //TRUE = dont display on page 
    'access_token' => 'token',
    'picture' => '@'. realpath($file),
    );
$createUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/events';


$test = fbcurl($createUrl, 'POST', $arrData); //Returns the event id

echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo '</pre>';

function fbcurl($url, $method, $fields = array(), $auth = array()){

foreach($fields as $key => $value){
    if(!is_string($value)){
        $fields[$key] = json_encode($value);
    }
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data'));
//  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
//  if(count($auth)===2)
//      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth['user'].':'.$auth['pass']);
//  }
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
if(count($fields)>0){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields, null, '&'));

}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'facebook-php-3.2');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data");
    //file_put_contents('fbcurllocal.txt', print_r(http_build_query($fields, null,        '&'),      true)."\n".$url);
$r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if($r!=''){
    $p = explode("\r\n\r\nHTTP/", $r);
    $p = (count($p) > 1 ? 'HTTP/' : '') . array_pop($p);
    list($h, $b) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $p, 2);
    return array('header' => $h, 'body' => $b);
}else{
    return array('header' => '', 'body' => 'error');
}
}
```

Comment: From where does `Koala.jpg` came?

Comment: it's saved in the same folder with the php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/), ther's no such field `picture` with `\POST /{page-id}/events`.

So, while creating an event you can not publish a cover picture along with it. So it's a two-step procedure-

1. **Create event**

   API: `\POST /{page-id}/events` - [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/)

   This you've already done, just delete the `picture` parameter from there.
2. **Upload cover picture**

   API: `\POST /{event-id}/events` - [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/picture/#publish)

   Give the image to the parameter: `source`

This way you can upload the cover pic to an event. Hope that helps.

---

**Edit**

The method to **upload cover photo** that I've mentioned will not work as of now (you can subscribe to this [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/274455709396178/) to get the update), instead you'll be needing a link to the image and make the call-

```
\POST /{event-id}
```

Parameter: `cover_url`

This works. I've tested!

Comment: Doesn't work! i have tested this 'picture' => '@'. realpath($file).';type=image/jpeg', bevore

Comment: the two-step precedure is correct. The API returns TRUE but nothing changes on the event...

Comment: now i have changed the "source" parameter to "asdf" an it always returns true :-(

Comment: The method we are following is correct, but it seems there's some kinda facebook bug. I found previous dates discussion regarding the same, but no one was able to solved it yet. Will let you know with any update

Comment: I communicated with the facebook guys, they said that documentation will be updated soon on this, as of now you can update the cover image only using the link- check how to do that in my edit

Answer (score 0):

look at the commtens before to understand it.

```
'asdf' => '@'. realpath($file).';type=image/jpeg',

(
[header] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-fb-rev: 1200162
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 10 Apr 2014 14:26:20 GMT
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-FB-Debug: nLKpXn4cbeF4AMa8kiOVMAfcKG5EFvQZmqvxFJXYC88=
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4
[body] => true
)
```

i tested this

```
'source' => '@'. realpath($file).';type=image/jpeg',
```

and this

```
'source' => '@'. realpath($file),
```

bevore