# Facebook event api to upload cover image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have working for facebook event creation if we set profile picture for the event which is working fine but while uploading cover image which is not working , " it throws #200 permission error" below is the code i have used from the post link [Facebook PHP SDK: Upload Event Cover Photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725574/facebook-php-sdk-upload-event-cover-photo?rq=1)

```
$cover['cover_url']  = 'http://urlofimage';
$eid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$eventUpdate = $facebook->api( "/" . $eid, 'post', $cover );
```

but its not worked still, can someone please help me.
OR please mention if its possible or not

Comment: found a solution, fixed the issue.

Comment: Pls post the answer here so that it may help others

Comment: I saw that you are online, but why you dont want to post the actual answer?

Comment: sorry for late reply, we need to set the accesstoken of the page using $this->setAccesstoken($pageaccesstoekn); which solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i use this code and its working fine .

```
 $data = array(
          "access_token"=>$fb_oauth_token,
          "cover_url" => $image_full,
         );
```

remember to use the accesstoken for posting etc.
thanks