# Upload event cover image on Facebook with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'd like to upload a cover image on a Facebook event page.

I use the php-sdk to publish events. This is an example to edit an existing event:

```
$event_param = array('name' => $EventName,'start_time' => $StartTime,'location' => $City,'description' => $description);
$img_file = $link_to_image;
$event_param[basename($img_file)] = '@' . realpath($img_file);
$result = $facebook->api('/' . $event_number,'post',$event_param);
```

But, what about the cover image? I mean the 851x350 px image.

I tried this (from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/picture/)

```
$response = $facebook->api("/" . $result['id'] . "/picture","POST",array ('source' => $LinkToJpeg,));
```

and this (from [Facebook PHP SDK: Upload Event Cover Photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725574/facebook-php-sdk-upload-event-cover-photo))

```
$cover['cover_url'] = $LinkToJpeg;
$eventUpdate = $facebook->api( "/" . $result['id'], 'post', $cover );
```

where $LinkToJpeg is something like "http://www.example.org/mypicture.jpg.

Both examples do not work ...

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What's the `response`?

Comment: I get this message: Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported post request. thrown in facebook-php-sdk-master/src/base_facebook.php on line 1271.

Comment: The same goes also for the 2nd solution (that with the cover_url field).

Comment: The second example works fine for me, dont for you?

Comment: No, I get "Unsupported post request". Checking my access token here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, I have this answer: public_profile, basic_info, read_stream, publish_checkins, status_update, photo_upload, video_upload, create_event, rsvp_event, create_note, share_item, export_stream, publish_stream, manage_pages, publish_actions, user_events, user_friends

Comment: Probably you are giving the wrong event_id, coz I've tested and it is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works! Thanks to Mittal!

There were 2 errors!

The first was that I had only the "create_event" permission. My facebook token is now enabled for the following actions:
public_profile, basic_info, read_stream, publish_checkins, status_update, photo_upload, video_upload, create_event, rsvp_event, create_note, share_item, export_stream, publish_stream, manage_pages, publish_actions, user_events, user_friends

Probably the photo_upload permission was missing!

So when I create the event I add  the following code

```
$cover['cover_url'] = $LinkToJpeg;
$eventUpdate = $facebook->api( "/" . $result['id'], 'post', $cover );
```

and I get a new event with a cover!

The second error was to try to update the cover image with the same code!
This is the right solution:

```
$event_param['cover_url'] = $LinkToJpeg; 
$result = $facebook->api('/' . $codice_evento_fb,
        'post',
        $event_param
    );
```